# completely deleting NAs in [R]

Tags: r, var, na

I am trying to conduct VAR function in R. I have data set as below.

```
library(vars)

`Riskp <- data.frame(dayahead2$Date, Risk, DF5$Load_DE, DF5$`DF2$MW_sol`, DF5$`DF3$MW_Wind`)` 

> head(Riskp)
dayahead2.Date  Risk DF5.Load_DE DF5..DF2.MW_sol. DF5..DF3.MW_Wind.
1     2011-01-02 26.91       43949                0          7396.450
2     2011-01-02 15.15       41708                0          7237.775
3     2011-01-02 13.17       40489                0          6956.850
4     2011-01-02 13.30       39711                0          6875.775
5     2011-01-02 15.20       39407                0          6599.275
6     2011-01-02 19.15       38394                0          6270.750
```

And then I have done
`Riskp1 <- na.omit(Riskp)` 
to take the NAs out. As a result, NAs are taken out from data as below.

from this:

> str(Riskp)

```
'data.frame':   43800 obs. of  5 variables:
```

to this:

> str(Riskp1)

```
'data.frame':   43787 obs. of  5 variables:
```

Now I want to do VAR test. By doing, let's say, `VAR(Riskp1, type = "both", lag.max = 10, ic = "AIC")`.

But it shows that there is NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'.

```
> VAR(Riskp1,type="both",lag.max = 10,ic="AIC")
Error in lm.fit(x = ys.lagged, y = yendog) : 
  'x' 내에 NA/NaN/Inf가 있습니다 <- (meaning "there is NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'")
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lm.fit(x = ys.lagged, y = yendog) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In lm.fit(x = ys.lagged, y = yendog) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I thought I deleted NAs. But seems like it is still there. How can I delete completely from my data?

Thank you people in advance.

Comment: Hello. I actually did with RIskp1. I edited my content correctly. But I still have the same issue.

Comment: Hello. Except for the date is in date class, everything is numeric. Is the date making problem? Then how can I solve the problem? but I want date of the data to be there so check if date is right..

Comment: The class is Date. `> class(Riskp1$dayahead2.Date)
[1] "Date"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `Date` column. For the VAR function to work with dates you need to supply a `ts` object. Here is an example:

```
library(vars)
library(zoo)

df <- read.table(text = "dayahead2.Date  Risk DF5.Load_DE DF5..DF2.MW_sol. DF5..DF3.MW_Wind.
           1     2011-01-02 26.91       43949                0          7396.450
           2     2011-01-02 15.15       41708                0          7237.775
           3     2011-01-02 13.17       40489                0          6956.850
           4     2011-01-02 13.30       39711                0          6875.775
           5     2011-01-02 15.20       39407                0          6599.275
           6     2011-01-02 19.15       38394                0          6270.750", header = T)
```

replicate the df 10 times since `VAR` throws an error related to too little observations:

```
df <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), times = 10),]
df$dayahead2.Date <- as.Date(df$dayahead2.Date) #convert to date
```

convert numeric columns to a matrix

```
mat <- as.matrix(df[,2:ncol(df)])
```

convert to `ts` object:

```
Zoo <- ts(zoo(mat, df$dayahead2.Date))
```

use the VAR function:

```
VAR(Zoo, type="both",lag.max = 10,ic="AIC")
```

Comment: So much appreciated. Thank you!